# Do there always exist such gcd integers....

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $x,y$ be integers and $\gcd(x,y) = 1$.  Then we can write $rx + sy = 1$.  But I'd like more info about $r$ and $s$.  Can $r$ and $s$ always be chosen so that $r - 1 \neq my$ and $s-1 \neq nx$ for any $m,n \in \Bbb{Z}$?

Comment: Let $(r_0, s_0)$ be any such pair. Then every other pair is on the form $(r_0 + yk, s_0 - xk)$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Let $x=y=1$. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: For $x, y, z \gt 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $x=5$ and $y=4$. Then the numbers $r$ and $s$ that work are $r=1+4k$, $s=-1-5k$. In particular $r-1$ is divisible by $y$ always.

**Remark:** If **some** $r_0-1$ is divisible by $y$, they all are, and the same applies to $s_0-1$ and $x$. This is an immediate consequence of the procedure for generating all solutions.